# React Native, how to toggle view smoothly in list view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a hidden View in each item View of the list view. And I want to display or hide(Toggling) the hidden view by clicking the item View.
I tried with State, storing the opened id list in the state like the example code below. It works with less than 30 items, but with more than 50, or 100, it reacts slowly and blinks when the screen update.
Is there a better way for implementing a toggle view that reacts fast and without blinks?

This is the code How I'm doing,

```
const [openIds, setOpenIds] = useState([]);

const toggleOpenToggleView = (id) => {
    let idx = openIds.indexOf(id)
    if (idx === -1) {
        // if id is not in openIds, add it
        setOpenIds([...openIds, id])
    } else {
        // if id is in openIds, remove it
        let pre = [...openIds]
        pre.splice(idx, 1)
        setOpenIds(pre)
    }
}

const ListItemView = ({item}) => (
    <View style={[styles.row, styles.item]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleOpenToggleView(item.id)}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between',}}>
                <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.itemName}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        {openIds.indexOf(item.id) > -1 &&
            <View style={[styles.row, styles.toggleContent]}>
                <Text>{item.toggleContent}</Text>
            </View>
        }
    </View>
)

<SwipeListView data={data} renderItem={({item}) => <ListItemView item={item}/>}
                           keyExtractor={item => item.id}
```

The is the version that I'm using

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.7",
```

Comment: What is SwipreListview ??

Comment: https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view

Comment: MAybe a flatlist would be helpful here? https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist